# Can I make a column in a library on SharePoint UNsearchable?

Tags: search, column, library

Is there a way to make one column in a SharePoint library UNsearchable?  Basically I have a list that contains documents, dates and a column for "comments".  I want that "comments" column to NOT populate in search results.  Is this a possibility?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the NoCrawl property to true of that field using powershell as below:

```
$WebURL  = "https://sitecollectionurl"
$FieldName = "Comments"

$web = Get-SPWeb $WebURL
$Field = $web.Fields[$FieldName]       

$Field.NoCrawl = $true
$Field.Update($true)
```

You can also use Server object model using C# as below:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("https://sitecollectionurl"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        SPField field = web.Fields["Comments"];
        field.NoCrawl = true;                    
        field.Update();
    }
}
```

If you want a no code solution, try below steps:

1) login as site admin

2) Go to site settings > site administration > Searchable columns

3) Find your column and uncheck it as below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I love the no code solution, but when I follow steps 1 through 3, I don't see the column name - the one that I created.  Can you advise?

Comment: Looks like it isn't a site column. You can download the SharePoint Manager 2013 tool  [SP Manager 2013](https://spm.codeplex.com/) and change it property through UI instead of coding. The second screenshot shows the usage of that tool. Its a codeplex tool and you can install it on the machine. There is no licensing issue involved in using that tool.

Comment: In order to make it a managed property, does the site column have to be "Managed Metadata" or can it be free form text?

Comment: it could be of any type, including text , managed metadata, choice , multiline etc.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done on the Search Service Application

- navigate to Central Admin -> App Mangement -> Manage Service App
- click Search Service App
- click Search Schema on left
- edit or delete the property name you're interested in

Answer (score 0):

There are couple ways you can think about.

- In order to be searchable, SP Crawl service just creates managed property for a site column. So, as long as your column isn't a site columns, it shouldn't be shown in the search. So, you can add a column throw List Setting->Create Column.
- Another option is to find out the managed property which was generated automatically by crawl service from your site column and remove that linked with the crawl property or disable it.